# How to display the barcodes so that they will use the entire paper in print?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

this code always displays the barcodes vertically while leaving empty spaces beside in print, is there any way for them to display side-by-side using the entire paper?

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center" wire:loading.class="opacity-50" id="bc">
                @foreach ($barcodes as $barcode)
                    <div class="lg:w-1/3 md:w-1/4 sm:w-1/2" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;     border-style: dashed;">
                         <p class="text-black font-bold text-lg text-center my-2">
                             {{ $barcode['name'] }}
                        </p>
                         <div class="flex justify-center">
                            {!! $barcode['barcode'] !!}
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-black font-bold text-lg text-center my-2">
                            {{ format_currency($barcode['price']) }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                 @endforeach
                </div>
            <div class="text-center my-3" id="printbc">
                 <x-button primary wire:click="downloadBarcodes" type="button" onclick="print()"      wire:loading.attr="disabled">
                    {{ __('Export PDF') }}
                </x-button>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function print() {
        var WinPrint = window.open();
         var printContent = document.getElementById("bc");
            WinPrint.document.write('<html><style>#bc{column-count:2;}</style>');
             WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
            WinPrint.document.write('</html>');
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
           WinPrint.close();
            window.location.reload();
};
 </script>
```

the output is like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hme4y.png)
I want it to align side by side thus consuming all paper space

Comment: HTML is not a layout language well suited for printouts. You should consider creating a PDF document on the fly instead which you can hand over to the client side printing system. Even then you do not have full control over the layout of the printout. Because you have no control over the printing system used on the client side.